# Validate Drivers License numbers?

Tags: c#, jquery, validation

I am working on a ACH payment processor and was wondering if I can scope the drivers license field against some rules. Any ideas on this? Can I assume numbers only or anything else more like SSN

Thanks

Comment: Certain key bits of info are missing - In which country? If in the US, in which state(s)? In the US DL#s seem to vary a lot state by state.

Comment: I would only do this if I had to. I don't know anything about US and Canadian drivers license numbering schemes, but I would expect any or all of them to be subject to occasional change. You might be headed for a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 9):

I came up with this for a project I was working on...

```
function utilities() {
function validateLicense(stateCode, licenseNumber) {
    // from http://www.uiia.org/documents/license_guidelines_08.pdf
    var oneToSevenNumeric = /^[0-9]{1,7}$/;
    var oneAlpha = /(.*[A-Za-z]){1}/;
    var oneAlphaPlusSeven = /^.[0-9]{7}$/;
    var twoAlpha = /(.*[A-Za-z]){2}/;
    var alphaPlusSixNumeric = /(.*[0-9]){6}$/;
    var threeToFiveNumeric = /(.*[0-9]){3,5}$/;
    var fiveToNineNumeric = /(.*[0-9]){5,9}/;
    var sixNumeric = /^[0-9]{6}$/;
    var sevenNumeric = /^[0-9]{7}$/;
    var sevenToNineNumeric = /^[0-9]{7,9}$/;
    var eightAreNumbers = /(.*[0-9]){8}/;
    var nineNumeric = /^[0-9]{9}$/;
    var nineAlphaChars = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{9}$/;
    var tenNumeric = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
    var elevenNumeric = /^.[0-9]{11}$/;
    var twelveNumeric = /^.[0-9]{12}$/;
    var hPlusEight = /([H][0-9]{8})$/;
    var sevenPlusX = /([H][0-9]{7}X)$/;

    if (stateCode == undefined || licenseNumber == undefined) {
        return "";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'AK') {
       return validateExpression(oneToSevenNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 1-7 numeric");
    }
    if (stateCode == 'AL') {
      return validateExpression(sevenNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 7 numeric");
    }
    if (stateCode == 'AR' || stateCode == 'MS') {
      return validateExpression(nineNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 9 numeric");
    }
    if (stateCode == 'AZ') { 
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) == true) {
            return "";
        }
        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && eightAreNumbers.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        if (twoAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && threeToFiveNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length < 8) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 Alphabetic, 8 Numeric; or 2 Alphabetic, 3-6 Numeric; or 9 Numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'CA') {

        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && oneAlphaPlusSeven.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 alpha and 7 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'CO' || stateCode == 'CN' || stateCode == 'CT') {
        return validateExpression(nineNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 9 numeric");
    }
    if (stateCode == 'DC') {
        if (sevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return  "Must be 7 - 9 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'DE') {
        if (oneToSevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 - 7 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'FL') {
        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && twelveNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 alpha, 12 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'GA') {
        if (sevenToNineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 7 - 9 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'HI') {
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || hPlusEight.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must 'H' + 8 numeric; 9 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'ID') {
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || sixNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || (twoAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && alphaPlusSixNumeric.test(licenseNumber))) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must 9 numbers or 6 numbers; or 2 char, 6 numbers ";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'IL') {
        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && elevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must 1 character 11 numbers";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'IN') {
        if (tenNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 9-10 numbers";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'IA') {
        if (nineAlphaChars.test(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 9 alpha numbers";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'KS' || stateCode == 'KY') {
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && eightAreNumbers.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 9)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 alpha and 8 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'LA') {
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) == true) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 9 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'ME') {
        if (sevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || sevenPlusX.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 7 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'MD' || stateCode == 'MI' || stateCode == 'MN') {
        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && twelveNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "1 Alphabetic, 12 Numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'MA') {
        if ((oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && eightAreNumbers.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 9) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 alpha, 8 numeric; 9 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'MO') {
        if ((oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && fiveToNineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length < 11) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "1 alpha - 5-9 Numeric or 9 numeric";
    }
    return "";
}

function validateExpression(expression, value, error) {
    if (expression.test(value) == true) {
        return "";
    }
    return error;
}

return {
    validateLicense: validateLicense,
    validateExpression: validateExpression
};
```

}

Comment: I used this code and it worked perfectly, thank you for your simple and thorough answer @james-fleming. My only question is, and there might be no answer, how to accept licenses that have older formats? For example, new jersey might change their format one year to a digit less, in which case this script would no longer work for nj..

Comment: The link to the pdf specification is currently broken. A link that works is this: https://www.uiia.org/sites/default/files/documents/license_guidelines_08.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I appreciated James' answer above, because it actually includes regex to answer this question, but it seems the drivers license formats he used are a little outdated in 2020. Here's the updated regex, if anyone needs it:

```
stateCode = $(<your-state-code-field>).children("option:selected").val();     
licenseNumber = $(<your-license-number-field>).attr("value");

// from https://ntsi.com/drivers-license-format/
// I opted only to set these three variables, because none of the other patterns are repeated
var sevenNumeric = /^[0-9]{7}$/;
var eightNumeric = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
var nineNumeric  = /^[0-9]{9}$/;

if (licenseNumber != 0 && (licenseNumber == "" || licenseNumber == 'null' || licenseNumber == 'undefined' || licenseNumber == false)) {
    error = "This field is required.";
} else if (stateCode == 'AK' || stateCode == 'DE') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{1,7}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 to 7 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'AL') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{1,8}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 to 8 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'AR') {
  if (!/^([0-9]){4,9}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
       error = "Must be 4 to 9 numeric.";
  }
} else if (stateCode == 'AZ') { 
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{8}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 alphabetic and 8 numeric or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'CA') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{7}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 alphabetic and 7 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'CO') {
  if (!(nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) && !(/^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9]{3,5}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length >= 4 ) ) {
       error = "Must be 9 numeric, or one alpha and 3 to 5 numeric, or 2 alpha and 2 to 5 numeric.";
  }
  
} else if (stateCode == 'CN' || stateCode == 'CT' || stateCode == 'MS') {
    if (!nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'DC' || stateCode == 'TN') {
    if (!sevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 7 or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'FL') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{12}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 alpha, 12 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'GA') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{7,9}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 7 to 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'HI') {
    if (!(/[0-9]{8}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 9)) {
        error = "Must have 1 alpha and 8 numeric, or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'ID') {
    if ( !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && !/[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{7}[A-Za-z]{1}$/.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must have 9 numeric, or 2 alphabetic + 6 numeric + 1 alpha.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'IL') {
    if ( !/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{11,12}$/.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must be 1 alphabetic 11 numeric, or 1 alpha and 12 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'IN') {
  if (!(/^[A-Za-z]{0,1}[0-9]{9,10}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length <= 10)) {
        error = "Must be one alpha and 9 numeric, or 9 to 10 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'IA') {
    if (!nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && !/^[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}$/.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must be 9 numeric, or 3 numeric + 2 alpha + 4 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'KS') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !( /^[A-Za-z]{0,1}[0-9]{8}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 9 )) {
        error = "Must be alpha + number + alpha + number + alpha, or 1 alpha and 8 numeric, or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'KY') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{8,9}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must be 1 alphabetic and 8 to 9 numeric, or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'LA' || stateCode == 'OR') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{1,9}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 to 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'ME') {
    if ( !( /^[0-9]{7,8}[A-Za-z]{0,1}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length <= 8)) {
        error = "Must be 7 numeric, 7 numeric and one alpha, or 8 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'MD' || stateCode == 'MN') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{12}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 alphabetic and 12 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'MA') {
    if (!(/[0-9]{8}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 9)) {
        error = "Must be 1 alphabetic and 8 numeric, or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'MI') {
   if (!(/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{10,12}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length != 12)) {
     error = "Must be 1 alpha and 10 numeric, or 1 alpha and 12 numeric.";
   }
} else if (stateCode == 'MT') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{8}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && !/^[0-9]{13,14}$/.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must have one alpha and 8 numeric, or 9, 13, or 14 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'NE') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{6,8}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have one alpha and six to eight numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'NV') {
    if (!(/^[0-9]{9,12}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length != 11) && !/^[0-9]{8}[Xx]$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 9, 10, or 12 numeric, or eight numeric + X.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'NH') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{5}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 2 numeric + 3 alpha + 5 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'NJ') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{14}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have one alpha and 14 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'NM') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{8,9}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 8 or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'NY') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{7}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{18}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !eightNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && !/^[A-Za-z]{8}$/.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must have one alpha and 7 or 18 numeric, 8 or 9 numeric, or 8 alpha.";
    }    
} else if (stateCode == 'NC') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{1,12}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 1 to 12 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'ND') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{6}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must have 3 alpha and 6 numeric, or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'OH') {
    if (!(/^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9]{3,8}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length >= 5 && licenseNumber.length <= 9) && !eightNumeric.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must have one alpha and 4 to 8 numeric, 2 alpha and 3 to 7 numeric, or 8 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'OK') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{0,1}[0-9]{9}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have one alpha and 9 numeric, or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'PA') {
    if (!eightNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 8 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'RI') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{7}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{6}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 7 numeric + 1 alpha + 6 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'SC') {
    if (!/(^[0-9]){5,11}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 5 to 11 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'SD') {
    if (!(/(.*[0-9]){6,10}/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length != 11) ) {
        error = "Must have 6 to 10 numeric or 12 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'TX') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{7,8}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 7 to 8 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'UT') {
    if (!/(^[0-9]){4,10}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 4 to 10 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'VT') {
    if (!eightNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && ! /^([0-9]{7}[Aa])$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must have 8 numeric or 7 numeric plus 'A'.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'VI') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{8,11}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 alpha and eight to 11 numeric, or 9 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'WA') { //1-7Alpha+any combination of Alpha, Numeric, or * for a total of 12 characters
    if (!(/^[A-Za-z]{1,7}/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 12)) {
        error = "Must be 1 to 7 alpha and total 12 characters.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'WV') {
    if (!sevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && !/^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9]{5,6}$/.test(licenseNumber) ) {
        error = "Must be 7 numeric, or 1 to 2 alpha and 5 to 6 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'WI') {
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{13}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 alpha and 13 numeric.";
    }
} else if (stateCode == 'WY') {
    if (!/^[0-9]{9,10}$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 9 to 10 numeric.";
    }
} else { // if (stateCode == 'MO')
    if (!/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{5,9}$/.test(licenseNumber) && !(/^[0-9]{8,9}[A-Za-z]{1,2}$/.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 10) && !nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && !/^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{6}[Rr]$/.test(licenseNumber)) {
        error = "Must be 1 alphabetic and 5-9 numeric, eight numeric and two alpha, or 9 numeric and one alpha, or 9 numeric, or 1 alpha + 9 numeric + R.";
    }
}
// update the error message, and prevent user from continuing if error is present
if (error != "") {
  $(<your-error-field>).text(error);
   return false;
} else {
   return true;
}
```

Assuming your form looks something like this:

```
<form name="customer-form" action="" method="post">
    <select id="<your-state-code-field>">
      <option value="CA">CA</option>
      <option value="NV">NV</option>
      <option value="ME">ME</option>
      ...
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="<your-license-number-field>" name="drivers-license">
    <div id="<your-error-field>" class="error-msg"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

I'm no regex or license expert, so if I missed anything, or could improve this code in any way let me know.

Comment: Has it been 5 years already? Thanks for the contribution! When we help each other, we make the world a better place.

Comment: @JamesFleming I hope so! At least with accurate license validation :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PHP implementation I wrote based on the https://ntsi.com/drivers-license-format/ recommendations. This has been unit tested.

```
/**
 * Based on https://ntsi.com/drivers-license-format/
 * Does not provide validation for territories such as Guam, American Samoa, etc
 * @param $license string
 * @param $state string Lowercase, two character state abbreviation
 * @param bool $returnFalseOnUnmatchedState
 * @return bool
 */
 function isValidLicense(string $license, string $state, $returnFalseOnUnmatchedState = true): bool
{
    $license = strtolower($license);
    $state = strtoupper($state);

    $sevenNumeric = '~^[0-9]{7}$~';
    $eightNumeric = '~^[0-9]{8}$~';
    $nineNumeric  = '~^[0-9]{9}$~';

    if (!$license) {
        return false;
    }

    switch ($state) {
        case 'AK': // Alaska
            // 1-7 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{1,7}$~', $license);
        case 'AL': // Alabama
            // 1-8 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{1,8}$~', $license);
        case 'AR': // Arkansas
            // 4-9 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{4,9}$~', $license);
        case 'AZ': // Arizona
        case 'MA': // Massachusetts
            /**x
             * 1 Alpha + 8 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{8}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'CA': // California
            // 1 Alpha + 7 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{7}$~', $license);
        case 'CO': // Colorado
            /*
             * 9 Numeric or
             * 1 Alpha + 3-6 Numeric or
             * 2 Alpha + 2-5 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{3,6}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2,5}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'CT': // Conneticut
        case 'MS': // Mississippi
            // 9 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match($nineNumeric, $license);
        case 'DC': // District of Columbia
        case 'TN': // Tennessee
            /*
             * 7 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match($sevenNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'DE': // Deleware
            // 1-7 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{1,7}$~', $license);
        case 'FL': // Florida
        case 'MN': // Minnesota
        case 'MD': // Maryland
            // 1 Alpha + 12 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{12}$~', $license);
        case 'GA': // Georgia
            // 7-9 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{7,9}$~', $license);
        case 'HI': // Hawaii
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 8 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{8}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'IA': // Iowa
            /*
             * 9 Numeric or
             * 3 Numeric + 2 Alpha + 4 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{3}[a-z]{2}[0-9]{4}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'ID': // Idaho
            /*
             * 2 Alpha + 6 Numeric + 1 Alpha or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{6}[a-z]$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'IL': // Illinois
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 11 Numeric or
             * 1 Alpha + 12 Numeric
             */
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{11,12}$~', $license);
        case 'IN': // Indiana
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 9 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric or
             * 10 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{9}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{9,10}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'KS': // Kansas
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 1 Numeric + 1 Alpha + 1 Numeric + 1 Alpha or
             * 1 Alpha + 8 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[A-Za-z]{0,1}[0-9]{8}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'KY': // Kentucky
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 8 Numeric or
             * 1 Alpha + 9 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{8,9}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'LA': // Louisiana
        case 'OR': // Oregon
            // 1-9 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{1,9}$~', $license);
        case 'ME': // Maine
            /*
             * 7 Numeric or
             * 7 Numeric + 1 Alpha or
             * 8 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{7}[a-z]{1}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($sevenNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match($eightNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'MI': // Michigan
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 10 Numeric or
             * 1 Alpha + 12 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{10}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{12}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'MO': // Missouri
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 5-9 Numeric or
             * 1 Alpha + 6 Numeric + R or
             * 8 Numeric + 2 Alpha or
             * 9 Numeric + 1 Alpha or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{5,9}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{6}r$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{8}[a-z]{2}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{9}[a-z]{1}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'MT': // Montana
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 8 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric or
             * 13 Numeric or
             * 14 Numeric
             */
            return (bool)(
                preg_match('~^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{8}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{13}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{14}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'NC': // North Carolina
            // 1-12 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{1,12}$~', $license);
        case 'ND': // North Dakota
            /*
             * 3 Alpha + 6 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{6}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'NE': // Nebraska
            // 1 Alpha + 6-8 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{6,8}$~', $license);
        case 'NH': // New Hampshire
            // 2 Numeric + 3 Alpha + 5 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{2}[a-z]{3}[0-9]{5}$~', $license);
        case 'NJ': // New Jersy
            // 1 Alpha + 14 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{14}$~', $license);
        case 'NM': // New Mexico
            // 8-9 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{8,9}$~', $license);
        case 'NV': // Nevada
            /*
             * 9 Numeric or
             * 10 Numeric or
             * 12 Numeric or
             * X + 8 Numeric
             */
            return (bool)(
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{10}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{12}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^x[0-9]{8}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'NY': // New York
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 7 Numeric or
             * 1 Alpha + 18 Numeric or
             * 8 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric or
             * 16 Numeric or
             * 8 Alpha
             */
            return (bool)(
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{7}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{18}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($eightNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{16}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{8}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'OH': // Ohio
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 4-8 Numeric or
             * 2 Alpha + 3-7 Numeric or
             * 8 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{4,8}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{3,7}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($eightNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'OK': // Oklahoma
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 9 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{9}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'PA': // Pennsylvania
            // 8 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match($eightNumeric, $license);
        case 'RI': // Rhode Island
            /*
             * 7 Numeric or
             * 1 Alpha + 6 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match($sevenNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{6}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'SC': // South Carolina
            // 5-11 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{5,11}$~', $license);
        case 'SD': // South Dakota
            /*
             * 6-10 Numeric or
             * 12 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{6,10}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{12}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'TX': // Texas
            // 7-8 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{7,8}$~', $license);
        case 'UT': // Utah
            // 4-10 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{4,10}$~', $license);
        case 'VT': // Vermont
            /*
             * 8 Numeric or
             * 7 Numeric+A
             */
            return (
                preg_match($eightNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[0-9]{7}a$~', $license)
            );
        case 'VA': // Virginia
            /*
             * 1 Alpha + 8-11 Numeric or
             * 9 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{8,11}$~', $license) ||
                preg_match($nineNumeric, $license)
            );
        case 'WA': // Washington
            // 1-7 Alpha + any combination of Alpha, Numeric, or * for a total of 12 characters
            return (
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{1,7}[a-z0-9*]{5,11}$~', $license)
                && strlen($license) == 12
            );
        case 'WV': // West Virginia
            /*
             * 7 Numeric or
             * 1-2 Alpha + 5-6 Numeric
             */
            return (
                preg_match($sevenNumeric, $license) ||
                preg_match('~^[a-z]{1,2}[0-9]{5,6}$~', $license)
            );
        case 'WI': // Wisconsin
            // 1 Alpha + 13 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[a-z][0-9]{13}$~', $license);
        case 'WY': // Wyoming
            // 9 - 10 Numeric
            return (bool)preg_match('~^[0-9]{9,10}$~', $license);
        default:
            return !$returnFalseOnUnmatchedState;
    }
}
```

**Please note that @Jillian Hoenig's answer has incorrect validations in many places. I do not have enough rep, otherwise I would comment and warn other users.**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your in the USA each state has different formats for their driver license numbers so as far I know you would have validations on a state wide basis. This site should get you started w/ validation by driver's license number:

http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/numbers/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in C#. Warning: Not yet tested.

```
private bool IsValidDriverLicense(string driverLicense,string applicantState)
        {
            driverLicense = Regex.Replace(driverLicense, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(applicantState) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(driverLicense))
            {
                return true;
            }
            #region Regex
            Regex oneToSevenNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{1,7}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex oneAlpha = new Regex("(.*[A-Za-z]){1}",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex oneAlphaPlusSeven = new Regex("^.[0-9]{7}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex hasOneAlphaPlusSeven = new Regex("[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{7}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex oneAlphaPlusEight = new Regex("^.[0-9]{8}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex oneAlphaPlusNine = new Regex("^.[0-9]{9}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex oneAlphaPlusEighteen= new Regex("^.[0-9]{18}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex twoAlpha  = new Regex("(.*[A-Za-z]){2}",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex threeAlpha = new Regex("(.*[A-Za-z]){3}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex eightAlpha = new Regex("(.*[A-Za-z]){8}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex alphaPlusSixNumeric  = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){6}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex threeToFiveNumeric  = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){3,5}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex fourToTenNumeric = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){4,10}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex fiveToNineNumeric = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){5,9}",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex fiveToElevenNumeric = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){5,11}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sixToTenNumeric = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){6,10}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex eightToElevenNumeric = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){8,11}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sixNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{6}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sevenNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{7}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex eightNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{8}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sixteenNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{16}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sevenToNineNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{7,9}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sevenToEightNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{7,8}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex fourToEightAreNumbers= new Regex("(.*[0-9]){4,8}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex threeToSevenAreNumbers = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){3,7}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex oneToNineNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{1,9}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex oneToTwelveNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{1,12}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex eightAreNumbers  = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){8}",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex fiveAreNumbers = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){5}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sixAreNumbers = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){6}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex nineNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{9}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex nineAlphaChars = new Regex("^[A-Za-z0-9]{9}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex tenNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{10}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex elevenNumeric = new Regex("^.[0-9]{11}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex twelveNumeric = new Regex("^.[0-9]{12}$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex hPlusEight = new Regex("([H][0-9]{8})$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sevenPlusX = new Regex("([H][0-9]{7}X)$",RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex sevenPlusA = new Regex("([H][0-9]{7}A)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex plusXEight = new Regex("^X([0-9]X{8})$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex thirteenToFourteenNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{13,14}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex hasThirteenNumeric = new Regex("[0-9]{13}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex eightToNineNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{8,9}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex hasSixToEightNumeric = new Regex("[0-9]{6,8}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex nineToTeenNumeric = new Regex("^[0-9]{9,10}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex fourteenAreNumbers = new Regex("(.*[0-9]){14}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            #endregion

            #region Matches
            MatchCollection matchesOneToSevenNumeric = oneToSevenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesOneAlpha = oneAlpha.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesOneAlphaPlusSeven = oneAlphaPlusSeven.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesHasOneAlphaPlusSeven = hasOneAlphaPlusSeven.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesOneAlphaPlusEight = oneAlphaPlusEight.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesOneAlphaPlusNine = oneAlphaPlusNine.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesOneAlphaPlusEigthteen = oneAlphaPlusEighteen.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesTwoAlpha = twoAlpha.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesThreeAlpha = threeAlpha.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesEightAlpha = eightAlpha.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesAlphaPlusSixNumeric = alphaPlusSixNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesThreeToFiveNumeric = threeToFiveNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesFourToTenNumeric = fourToTenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesFiveToNineNumeric = fiveToNineNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesFiveToElevenNumeric = fiveToElevenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSixToTenNumeric = sixToTenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesEightToElevenNumeric = eightToElevenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSixNumeric = sixNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesEightNumeric = eightNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSixteenNumeric = sixteenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSevenNumeric = sevenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSevenToNineNumeric = sevenToNineNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSevenToEightNumeric = sevenToEightNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesOneToNineNumeric = oneToNineNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesOneToTwelveNumeric = oneToTwelveNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesEightAreNumbers = eightAreNumbers.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesFiveAreNumbers = fiveAreNumbers.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSixAreNumbers = sixAreNumbers.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesNineNumeric = nineNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesNineAlphaChars = nineAlphaChars.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesTenNumeric = tenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesElevenNumeric = elevenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesTwelveNumeric = twelveNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesHPlusEight = hPlusEight.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSevenPlusX = sevenPlusX.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesSevenPlusA = sevenPlusA.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesPlusXEight = plusXEight.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesThirteenToFourteenNumeric = thirteenToFourteenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesEightToNineNumeric = eightToNineNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesHasSixToEightNumeric = hasSixToEightNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection machesNineToTeenNumeric = nineToTeenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection machesFourteenAreNumbers = fourteenAreNumbers.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection machesFourToEightAreNumbers = fourToEightAreNumbers.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection machesThreeToSevenAreNumbers = threeToSevenAreNumbers.Matches(driverLicense);
            MatchCollection matchesHasThirteenNumeric = hasThirteenNumeric.Matches(driverLicense);
            #endregion

            if (applicantState.Contains("AK"))
            {
                if(matchesOneToSevenNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("AL"))
            {
                if(matchesSevenNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("AR") || applicantState.Contains("MS"))
            {
                if(matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("AZ"))
            {
                if (matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if(matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesEightAreNumbers.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if(matchesTwoAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesThreeToFiveNumeric.Count >0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("CA"))
            {
                if(matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesOneAlphaPlusSeven.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("CO") || applicantState.Contains("CN") || applicantState.Contains("CT"))
            {
                if(matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("DC"))
            {
                if(matchesSevenNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("DE"))
            {
                if(matchesOneToSevenNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("FL"))
            {
                if(matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesTwelveNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("GA"))
            {
                if (matchesSevenToNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("HI"))
            {
                if (matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesHPlusEight.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("ID"))
            {
                if (matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesSixNumeric.Count > 0 || (matchesTwoAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesAlphaPlusSixNumeric.Count > 0))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("IL"))
            {
                if (matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesElevenNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("IN"))
            {
                if (matchesTenNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("IA"))
            {
                if (matchesNineAlphaChars.Count > 0 || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("KS") || applicantState.Contains("KY"))
            {
                if (matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0 || (matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesEightAreNumbers.Count > 0 && driverLicense.Length == 9))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("LA"))
            {
                if (matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("ME"))
            {
                if (matchesSevenNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesSevenPlusX.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("MD") || applicantState.Contains("MI") || applicantState.Contains("MN"))
            {
                if (matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesTwelveNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("MA"))
            {
                if ((matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesEightAreNumbers.Count > 0 && driverLicense.Length == 9) || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("MO"))
            {
                if ((matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesFiveToNineNumeric.Count > 0 && driverLicense.Length < 11) || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("MT"))
            {
                if ((matchesOneAlphaPlusEight.Count > 0) || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesThirteenToFourteenNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("NE"))
            {
                if (matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesHasSixToEightNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("NV"))
            {
                if (machesNineToTeenNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesTwelveNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesPlusXEight.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("NH"))
            {
                if (matchesThreeAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesEightAreNumbers.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("NJ"))
            {
                if (matchesThreeAlpha.Count > 0 && machesFourteenAreNumbers.Count > 0 && driverLicense.Length == 15)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("NM"))
            {
                if (matchesEightToNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("NY"))
            {
                if (matchesOneAlphaPlusSeven.Count > 0 || matchesOneAlphaPlusEigthteen.Count > 0 || matchesEightToNineNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesSixteenNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesEightAlpha.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("NC"))
            {
                if (matchesOneToTwelveNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("ND"))
            {
                if ((matchesThreeAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesSixAreNumbers.Count > 0 && driverLicense.Length == 9) || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("OH"))
            {
                if (
                    (matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && machesFourToEightAreNumbers.Count > 0) && (driverLicense.Length >= 5 && driverLicense.Length <=9) ||
                    (matchesTwoAlpha.Count > 0 && machesThreeToSevenAreNumbers.Count > 0) && (driverLicense.Length >= 5 && driverLicense.Length <= 9) ||
                    matchesEightNumeric.Count > 0
                    )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("OK"))
            {
                if (matchesOneAlphaPlusNine.Count > 0 || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("OR"))
            {
                if (matchesOneToNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("PA"))
            {
                if (matchesEightAreNumbers.Count > 0 && driverLicense.Length == 8)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("RI"))
            {
                if (matchesSevenNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesAlphaPlusSixNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("SC"))
            {
                if (matchesFiveToElevenNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("SD"))
            {
                if (matchesSixToTenNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesTwelveNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("TN"))
            {
                if (matchesSevenToNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("TX"))
            {
                if (matchesSevenToEightNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("UT"))
            {
                if (matchesFourToTenNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("VT"))
            {
                if (matchesEightNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesSevenPlusA.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("VA"))
            {
                if ((matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesEightToElevenNumeric.Count > 0) && (driverLicense.Length >= 9 && driverLicense.Length <= 12) || matchesNineNumeric.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("WA"))
            {
                if (matchesHasOneAlphaPlusSeven.Count > 0 && driverLicense.Length == 12)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("WV"))
            {
                if (matchesSevenNumeric.Count > 0 || ((matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 || matchesTwoAlpha.Count > 0) && (matchesSixNumeric.Count > 0 || matchesFiveAreNumbers.Count > 0)))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("WI"))
            {
                if (matchesOneAlpha.Count > 0 && matchesHasThirteenNumeric.Count > 0 && driverLicense.Length == 14)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(applicantState.Contains("WY"))
            {
                if (machesNineToTeenNumeric.Count>0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: How do you know it works for you if you haven't tested it? Also, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing?

Comment: Because i added new states before the last test