# Driver's License Verification in Flutter / Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Does anyone know of an API or package that can be used in a flutter project that would allow me to check whether a driver's license number is valid or not? I'm working with US driver's licenses if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's no plugin for that yet, but since it can be done fairly the same way in most languages, it's been done already. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835561/6696558.

In Dart it would something like this:

```
class DriverLicenseValidator {
  // From http://www.uiia.org/documents/license_guidelines_08.pdf
  static final oneToSevenNumeric = RegExp(r'^[0-9]{1,7}$');
  static final oneAlpha = RegExp(r'(.*[A-Za-z]){1}');
  static final oneAlphaPlusSeven = RegExp(r'^.[0-9]{7}$');
  static final twoAlpha = RegExp(r'(.*[A-Za-z]){2}');
  static final alphaPlusSixNumeric = RegExp(r'(.*[0-9]){6}$');
  static final threeToFiveNumeric = RegExp(r'(.*[0-9]){3,5}$');
  static final fiveToNineNumeric = RegExp(r'(.*[0-9]){5,9}');
  static final sixNumeric = RegExp(r'^[0-9]{6}$');
  static final sevenNumeric = RegExp(r'^[0-9]{7}$');
  static final sevenToNineNumeric = RegExp(r'^[0-9]{7,9}$');
  static final eightAreNumbers = RegExp(r'(.*[0-9]){8}');
  static final nineNumeric = RegExp(r'^[0-9]{9}$');
  static final nineAlphaChars = RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z0-9]{9}$');
  static final tenNumeric = RegExp(r'^[0-9]{10}$');
  static final elevenNumeric = RegExp(r'^.[0-9]{11}$');
  static final twelveNumeric = RegExp(r'^.[0-9]{12}$');
  static final hPlusEight = RegExp(r'([H][0-9]{8})$');
  static final sevenPlusX = RegExp(r'([H][0-9]{7}X)$');

  /// If there's no error, returns an empty [String]
  /// If there's an error, returns an error [String]
  static String checkForError(String stateCode, String licenseNumber) {
    if (stateCode == null || licenseNumber == null) {
      return "";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'AK') {
      return _validateExpression(oneToSevenNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 1-7 numeric");
    }

    if (stateCode == 'AL') {
      return _validateExpression(sevenNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 7 numeric");
    }

    if (stateCode == 'AR' || stateCode == 'MS') {
      return _validateExpression(nineNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 9 numeric");
    }

    if (stateCode == 'AZ') {
      if (nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      if (oneAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) && eightAreNumbers.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      if (twoAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) &&
          threeToFiveNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) &&
          licenseNumber.length < 8) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 1 Alphabetic, 8 Numeric; or 2 Alphabetic, 3-6 Numeric; or 9 Numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'CA') {
      if (oneAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) && oneAlphaPlusSeven.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 1 alpha and 7 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'CO' || stateCode == 'CN' || stateCode == 'CT') {
      return _validateExpression(nineNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 9 numeric");
    }

    if (stateCode == 'DC') {
      if (sevenNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 7 - 9 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'DE') {
      if (oneToSevenNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 1 - 7 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'FL') {
      if (oneAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) && twelveNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 1 alpha, 12 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'GA') {
      if (sevenToNineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 7 - 9 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'HI') {
      if (nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) || hPlusEight.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must 'H' + 8 numeric; 9 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'ID') {
      if (nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) ||
          sixNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) ||
          (twoAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) && alphaPlusSixNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber))) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must 9 numbers or 6 numbers; or 2 char, 6 numbers ";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'IL') {
      if (oneAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) && elevenNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must 1 character 11 numbers";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'IN') {
      if (tenNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 9-10 numbers";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'IA') {
      if (nineAlphaChars.hasMatch(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 9 alpha numbers";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'KS' || stateCode == 'KY') {
      if (nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) ||
          (oneAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) &&
              eightAreNumbers.hasMatch(licenseNumber) &&
              licenseNumber.length == 9)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 1 alpha and 8 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'LA') {
      if (nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) == true) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 9 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'ME') {
      if (sevenNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) || sevenPlusX.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 7 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'MD' || stateCode == 'MI' || stateCode == 'MN') {
      if (oneAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) && twelveNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "1 Alphabetic, 12 Numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'MA') {
      if ((oneAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) &&
              eightAreNumbers.hasMatch(licenseNumber) &&
              licenseNumber.length == 9) ||
          nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "Must be 1 alpha, 8 numeric; 9 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'MO') {
      if ((oneAlpha.hasMatch(licenseNumber) &&
              fiveToNineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber) &&
              licenseNumber.length < 11) ||
          nineNumeric.hasMatch(licenseNumber)) {
        return "";
      }

      return "1 alpha - 5-9 Numeric or 9 numeric";
    }

    return "Invalid state code";
  }

  static String _validateExpression(RegExp expression, String value, String error) =>
      expression.hasMatch(value) ? "" : error;
}
```

Comment: This is very useful code for checking the structure of the drivers license that was entered, but I was referring to an API or package that could be used to check if the driver's license number is real and to verify the identity of users. I accepted this as the answer since my question was short and unclear about what I meant by verification.

Comment: I am searching for USDL pdf417 barcode raw data decoding options in flutter.If any one have those ideas please let me know..Thanks in advance